Can anybody explain how we can connect an apache ignite client to an apache ignite embedded server that is running with my spring boot application
Iam able to connect the ignite client with remote machine but its not possible to connect with local machine , which does not even givening any errors
    private static final String HOST = "127.0.0.1";
    private static final String PORT = "10800";
    private static final String CACHE_NAME = "thin-cache";
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("Simple Ignite thin client example working over TCP socket.");
        ClientConfiguration cfg = new ClientConfiguration().setAddresses(HOST + ":" + PORT);
        try (IgniteClient igniteClient = Ignition.startClient(cfg)) {
            ClientCache<String, String> clientCache = igniteClient.getOrCreateCache(CACHE_NAME);   
            // put a few value   
            clientCache.put("Moscow", "095");   
            clientCache.put("Vladimir", "033");   
            // get the region code of the Vladimir   
            String val = clientCache.get("Vladimir");   
            logger.info("Print value: {}", val);   
        } catch (IgniteException e) {   
            logger.error("Ignite exception:", e.getMessage());   
        } catch (Exception e) {   
            logger.error("Ignite exception:", e.getMessage());   
        }
    }


What happens? Does it time out? Can you connect from your local machine using something like sqlline?

The example code in the OP demonstrates use of 127.0.0.1 local-only IP address. If connection from a remote node works, then the remote client is able to use the embedded server's ignite instance bound to a non 127.* address. Using the same IP address used by the remote client when connecting from localhost will also work.
If you need to be able to connect to the ignite instance both from remote clients to server IP and also 127.0.0.1, then try explicitly setting IgniteConfiguration bind address to 0.0.0.0 (INADDR_ANY). If this has been set to a host IP, nothing will listen on 127.0.0.1.
https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/IgniteSystemProperties.html#IGNITE_LOCAL_HOST
The simplest way to ensure remote and local connections to 127.0.0.1 work the same is to set the IGNITE_LOCAL_HOST system property to "0.0.0.0".
